# Is there a way to get a visa to mainland China in Taipei (Taiwan)?

Tags: visas, china, taiwan, eu-citizens

I have a EU passport, I'm in Hong Kong now.

I want to go to Taiwan.

After Taiwan I want to go to mainland China. How can I get a visa for mainland while in Taiwan?